# Recover access to unregistered account

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

My old account was [23640](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/23640/yael), but suddenly I'm on a new account ([42687](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/42687/yael)). I had a bunch of questions on my old account; how do I recover it?

Comment: you need to log in with the same username and password as before...

Comment: If you know what email address you used to sign up, there's an account recovery form at http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery ; if you want to merge this account with your other one, there's a contact address at http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge (both those links are available from the 'help' link at the top of any page, then looking under the My Account section).

Answer (score 5):

[drewbenn's comment](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/how-to-register-again-to-unix-linux-cookies-was-deleted-from-my-pc#comment1932_1335) covers it; you need to use the [account recovery](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) page to fix it. Once you do get into your old account, you should [register it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) so you can login in the future